# NetSuite deployment to live environment

Tags: deployment, netsuite

in my company we are doing an investigation over NetSuite Deployment of new features to Live Environment.
Till this day, there was only 1 developer who was doing all the development and customizations in NetSuite. Problem is that nobody anticipated that one day there will be a whole development team and regular releases of new features in NetSuite.

Till this day all deployment from SandBox was done manually by that single developer who did all customizations. But this not acceptable with multiple developers doing development.

Can anyone tell me possible solutions of Automatic Deployment? Right now we are investigating Bundler as a possible solution, but we would like to see if there are more solutions like that to compare.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right track, you need suitebundler. The way it works is you 'package' your scripts, custom fields, custom records, etc. from the sandbox account and you make it available to other netsuite account (or public if that is intended).

Comment: Thank you,
As we are investigating, we found some high risks:
1) Once Installed, Bundle can only be Uninstalled, not reverted
     Any suggestion here? We think of using Copy to Repository as Backup of older version or Bundle Copy

2) We are doing SandBox Refreshes sometimes to have latest data in SandBox
     This would erase Source Bundle, any suggestion here? Is it possible to "export" bundle configuration somehow?

Comment: What about the delta of configurations/customizations between the production and sandbox accounts? I think its safe to assume that the sandbox can have a superset of configurations/customizations than are live in the production account. So, with that assumption, does the bundle that contains these items (an updated version of the bundle installed on production) remain intact when refreshing from production? If not, how can that delta be re-applied to the sandbox so that it doesn't have to be put on manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you refresh your sandbox, everything gets wiped out in your account if it's not in your production account.

Comment: Hi, after some investigation I found that this is no longer an issue.

Comment: As stated in NetSuite Help:

As of Version 2013 Release 2, the sandbox refresh process automatically restores bundle definitions in the sandbox account, completely eliminating this issue. The source bundle in sandbox continues to exist after sandbox refreshes, and the link between the source bundle and the target bundle in production is maintained. As a result of this change, a bundle installed into production from sandbox can be continually updated with changes made to the source bundle in sandbox.